# Why can't find the library: no such file to load

Tags: ruby, require

I'm stuck, can't find the cause, it's suppossed to be simple,

This is the error message:

> require': no such file to load -- ./ip (LoadError)

It's generated by this line of code:

```
require './ip'
```

As the 
require 'socket'
works and I found the two libraries:

> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-ip-0.9.1/lib/ip.rb
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-ip-0.9.1/lib/ip/socket.rb

tried also `require 'ip'` 
and
`require '../ip'`

still same error

---

Backgroun info:

I installled ruby-ip so that I could invoke a method like:  `ip = IP.new do ...`

> gem installed ruby-ip

I can see the library ( I believe it's the ip.rb what I need to use;

> pwd
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-ip-0.9.1/lib
>   ls
>   ip  ip.rb

### environment info

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-10-12 patchlevel 371) [i386-linux]
```

---

gem list

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

builder (3.2.0)
eventmachine (1.0.1, 0.12.10)
pg (0.14.1, 0.13.2)
ruby-ip (0.9.1)
rubygems-update (2.0.0)
sqlite3 (1.3.3)
```

---

which ruby

### /usr/bin/ruby

which gem

### /usr/bin/gem

gem environment

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.0
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2012-10-12 patchlevel 371) [i386-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
     - /home/pilar/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Comment: that is strange. I just did `gem install ruby-ip` and then `require 'ip'` with no problems

Comment: thanks, I had installed some others in the past with no issues.  For this one: ruby-ip ,I uninstalled it and installed it back, still the same issue.  Any recommendation?

Comment: aha! I just tried it with your ruby version (1.8.7) and it didn't work. It works fine with 1.9.3 or 2.0.0. Can you use a newer ruby?

Comment: thanks, very good, working on 1.9.3

Answer (score 0):

Are you including require 'rubygems' too? It is necessary if you are using rvm.

Example:

```
[fotanus@thing ~]$ gem install ip
Fetching: ip-0.3.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed ip-0.3.0
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for ip-0.3.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for ip-0.3.0...
[fotanus@thing ~]$ irb
1.8.7 :001 > require 'ip'
LoadError: no such file to load -- ip
    from (irb):1:in `require'
    from (irb):1
1.8.7 :002 > require 'rubygems'
 => true 
1.8.7 :003 > require 'ip'
 => true 
1.8.7 :004 >
```